# Mount point: inode/x-corrupted type

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, mount, raspberry-pi

[image]I mounted /dev/sdb1 to /mnt/MyFlashdrive. After mounting, the mount point turned into a **inode/x-corrupted type**.
There are no files inside the mount point and its permission is set to 777 and the owner is pi:pi

**Here is my fstab:**

/dev/mmcblk0p6  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2

/dev/mmcblk0p7  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1

UUID=37582F3C25B18299 /mnt/MyFlashdrive ntfs defaults,uid=pi,gid=pi,nofail,noatime 0 0

**stat /mnt/MyFlashdrive:**

stat: cannot stat '/mnt/MyFlashdrive': Transport endpoint is not connected

Comment: Where exactly do you see `inode/x-corrupted`?

Comment: the mount point folder and i cannot open or navigate through it because it turned into an inode/x-corrupted type. the mount point folder turns back to normal if it is not mounted

Comment: Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/576635/edit) the question with the output of  `stat /mnt/MyFlashdrive`.

Comment: do you mean the main question? or i will just add the details inside the body? --sorry i just started asking questions yesterday

Comment: Suggestion: unmount the flash drive. Try `sudo umount -l /mnt/MyFlashdrive`.

Comment: i tried umount and mount. but i want to mount /dev/sdb1 to /mnt/MyFlashdrive without an error